# Java recursively exercise

Tags: java, recursion

I'm in need of some guidance on the following exercise. 
I have a custom list in which it has cities, each city knows to which city it connects this is the route, the route has a time which it take you to get between cities. What im asked to do is: given a city and sometime X:

`public IList citiesWithRange(City c, int timeMinutes);`

I should return to all the cities I can reach within that time frame. IList is a list made by me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Go ahead and try to begin on your own. Once you have an attempt down, go ahead and add that to your question so we can help you get it working! If you're confused about a particular concept, be sure to mention that in your question. (Recursion in general is pretty broad and a few Google searches would clear up general questions)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an implementation of an algorithm which returns the paths between nodes in a graph.

Take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

This can be helpful too:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960208.html

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to solve this problem with a few easier steps in your recursive function

This function should be called on the starting city and be given a stack to add valid cities too, as well as an amount of time

1. Exit if time remaining is negative
2. Log current city to a stack
3. Loop through all connecting cities, calling the recursive function on each of them with the stack and time remaining minus travel time

At the end of this, the stack will contain all valid cities and may have duplicates

Remove the duplicates and you have all of the possible cities you can travel to